# Importing table from SQL server to XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to import information from SQL server to XML as well as trying to create an .xml file in E drive. However the code is shown below is not working:

```
    CREATE PROC x
    AS
    DECLARE @xmlOutput xml,
            @myFile varchar(8000)


    SET @xmlOutput= ( SELECT TOP 1000 [tmc_code]
                                ,[measurement_tstamp]
                                ,[speed]
                                ,[average_speed]
                                ,[reference_speed]
                                ,[travel_time_minutes]
                                ,[confidence_score]
                                ,[cvalue]
                                 FROM [INRIX_DATA].[dbo].[Sample]
                                 FOR XML AUTO)

    SET @myFile='E:\britain.xml'

    EXEC x
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx), and the [bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to achive this

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM MyTable FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS" queryout "E:\mytableFile.xml" -c -T'
```